# How to find all the methods of a class I have written in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have written a Ruby class that contains 3 methods and "includes" methods from other classes. How can I determine the names of the 3 methods I have written?

If this class is part of a module, how can I determine the names of the methods I have written i.e. methods not part of other "include" classes or ancestor classes?

Comment: Depends on whether these methods class methods or instance methods... There are a slew of methods around this myclass.instancemethods(false) for instance will give you an array of instance methods in the class. true would walk up the inheritance chain. There's bunch of 'em. Module.methods. class.public_instance_methods...

Comment: Was after instance methods but also a way to determine the file a class is defined it?

Comment: File the class is defined in? Hmmm, if it's not there. meta code I think. Create a static method that uses ___FILE__ to set it self. But if you re-open the same class in another file, what happens.... Interesting that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyClass.instance_methods(false)
```

The false tells it not to include inherited methods.

Example:

```
class A
  def method1
  end
end

class B < A
  def method2
  end
end

puts B.instance_methods(false)
```

This outputs `method2`.

There is no need to manually exclure the methods of ancestors and mixins.

Comment: And this properly deals with methods from mixins that you've overridden. I think your example is missing a `< A`, no?

Comment: @muistooshort: And is the idiomatic, built-in way to do it. And... And... :)

Comment: @muistooshort: And has a completely wrong example! (Thanks, fixed).

Comment: You could also toss in some a mixin and an [`UnboundMethod#owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-owner) call if you wanted to be really explicit.

Comment: @muistooshort: What do you mean?

Comment: Given `module M; def m; end; def n; end; end` and `class C; include M; def m; end; def c; end; end`, compare what `C.instance_method(x).owner` says when `x` is `:m`, `:n`, and `:c`.

Comment: @muistooshort: Ah. I get it.

Comment: If I've written my classes in a file a.rb, how can I search a module only for classes defined in that file? Thats what the second part of the question was getting at.

Comment: @user3200595: What do you mean "search a module"?

Comment: I've put all my classes into a Module which I use in my main program. So how can I search this Module for classes that originate from a specific file? Knowing this I can then use instance_methods(false) to locate the methods that I actually wrote in the class file.

Comment: @user3200595: Here's a bit of a hack. To get the file a class was defined in, try this: `MyClass.instance_method(MyClass.instance_methods(false)[0]).source_location.first`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of `public methods` that are only part of the class use `public_methods(false)`

You can get more ways to get methods out of a class instance in the `Object` documentation http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#

#### EXAMPLE

```
[7] pry(main)> p "".public_methods(false);
[:<=>, :==, :===, :eql?, :hash, :casecmp, :+, :*, :%, :[], :[]=, :insert, :length, :size, :bytesize, :empty?, :=~, :match, :succ, :succ!, :next, :next!, :upto, :index, :rindex, :replace, :clear, :chr, :getbyte, :setbyte, :byteslice, :to_i, :to_f, :to_s, :to_str, :inspect, :dump, :upcase, :downcase, :capitalize, :swapcase, :upcase!, :downcase!, :capitalize!, :swapcase!, :hex, :oct, :split, :lines, :bytes, :chars, :codepoints, :reverse, :reverse!, :concat, :<<, :prepend, :crypt, :intern, :to_sym, :ord, :include?, :start_with?, :end_with?, :scan, :ljust, :rjust, :center, :sub, :gsub, :chop, :chomp, :strip, :lstrip, :rstrip, :sub!, :gsub!, :chop!, :chomp!, :strip!, :lstrip!, :rstrip!, :tr, :tr_s, :delete, :squeeze, :count, :tr!, :tr_s!, :delete!, :squeeze!, :each_line, :each_byte, :each_char, :each_codepoint, :sum, :slice, :slice!, :partition, :rpartition, :encoding, :force_encoding, :b, :valid_encoding?, :ascii_only?, :unpack, :encode, :encode!, :to_r, :to_c, :shellsplit, :shellescape]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of methods by calling .methods on any ruby object, but as far as I know using mixin style includes does not leave any breadcrumbs that you would be able to backtrack and find 'actual' methods vs 'included' methods.

Comment: Yeah, you just query the mixin for it's methods, and then reject them from those in the class.

Comment: but how do you know about the mixin in the first place?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: But what happens if you include something that defines a method `m` and then you override `m` yourself? You can't just blindly toss `m` away because the mixing provides it.

Comment: A good way to see what can be done is to look at the should matchers in RSpec. If you are using mixins, you should already have a test on the class that you haave. :)

Comment: @muistooshort If you are doing that you've got bigger problems than this. I can't think of a good reason to do something like that. You might as well successively monkey patch string based on a random number.

Comment: @Tony: A mixing may provide an implementation that works most of the time but needs to be overridden in specific cases to force it to match reality. Happens all the time.

Comment: Not to me it doesn't! I'd namespace the mixin module, and then mix in the parts that I wanted.